# How do you create your own data dictionary/structure in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, scikit-learn, spyder

In the `sci-kit learn` python library there are many datasets accessed easily by the following commands:

for example to load the `iris` dataset:

`iris=datasets.load_iris()`

And we can now assign data and target/label variables as follows:

`X=iris.data  # assigns feature dataset to X`

`Y=iris.target # assigns labels to Y`

My question is how to create my own data dictionary using my own data either in csv, xml or any other format into something similar above so data can be called easily and features/labels are easily accessed.
Is this possible? someone help me!!
By the way I am using the spyder (anaconda) platform by continuum.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see at least two (easy) solutions to your problem.

First, you can store your data in whichever structure you like.

```
# Storing in a list
my_list = []
my_list.append(iris.data)
my_list[0] # your data

# Storing in a dictionary
my_dict = {}
my_dict["data"] = iris.data
my_dict["data"] # your data
```

Or, you can create your **own class**:

```
Class MyStructure:
    def __init__(data, target):
        self.data = data
        self.target = target

my_class = MyStructure(iris.data, iris.target)
my_class.data # your data
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If ALL you want to do is read data from csv files and have them organized , I would recommend you to simply use either pandas or numpy's genfromtxt function.

```
mydata=numpy.genfromtxt(filepath,*params)
```

If the CSV is formatted regularly, you can extract for example the names of each column by specifying:

`mydata=numpy.genfromtxt(filepath,unpack=True,names=True,delimiter=',')`

then you can access any column data you want by simply typing it's name/header:

```
mydata['your header']
```

(Pandas also has a similar convenient way of grabbing data in an organized manner from CSV or similar files.)

However if you want to do it the long way and learn:

Simply, you want to write a class for the data that you are using, complete with its own access, modify, read, #dosomething functions. Instead of code for this, I think you would benefit more from going in and reading for example the iris class, or an introduction to a simple Class from any beginners guide to object based programming.

To do what you want, for an object *MyData*, you could have for example

- read(#file) function that reads from a given file of some expected format and returns some specified structure. For reading from csv files, you can simply use numpy's loadtxt method.
- modify(#some attribute)
- etc.